# Transit visa for a Pakistani passport holder for an 11-hour layover in Dubai

Tags: transit-visas, dubai, pakistani-citizens

I'm a Pakistani passport holder. I have booked my flight with Emirates from Kuwait to Pakistan. I have an 11-hour layover in Dubai. Can I get a transit visa on arrival in Dubai? What's the cost and procedure? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the journey from Kuwait to Pakistan is one ticket, then Emirates is bound to give you a hotel room under IATA rules. Emirates usually takes travellers to hotels out of the airport complex which requires them to cross immigration. Emirates should arrange this for you. You should contact them.

Edit: Apparently, there is a debate on whether the rules under the IATA are enforceable. In any case, emirates will provide accommodation and a visa for layovers longer than 8hrs.

https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/dubai-international-airport/dubai-connect.aspx

Comment: Which IATA rule is this?

Comment: https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/dubai-international-airport/dubai-connect.aspx

Comment: That's no IATA rule. That's a voluntary program offered by Emirates. They are not bound by any international rule to do that.

Comment: if emirates not provide hotel room and i book a hotel on my own expenses, may i leave the air port as per rules?

Comment: Your edit is not what I'm saying. I'm not talking about the *enforceability* of such a rule, I'm talking about the *presence* of such a rule. I don't think such a rule exists; can you link me to the actual IATA rule stating this?