# Process and eligibility for transit visa in Dubai for Pakistanis (21 hour layover)

Tags: transit-visas, pakistani-citizens, dubai, emirates, flydubai

I am a Pakistani who's travelling from Istanbul to Sialkot via **flydubai airlines**. I have a 21-hour layover in Dubai. My journey is as follows:

- Istanbul -- to -- Dubai
- (21 hour layover)
- Dubai -- to -- Sialkot

Can I get a transit visa on arrival in Dubai? What's the cost and procedure?

[Process and eligibility for transit visa in Dubai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/112898/process-and-eligibility-for-transit-visa-in-dubai) and [Transit visa for a Pakistani passport holder for an 11-hour layover in Dubai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/109303/transit-visa-for-a-pakistani-passport-holder-for-an-11-hour-layover-in-dubai) are related but neither gives a complete answer to this question.

Comment: https://www.flydubai.com/en/plan/visas-and-passports/uae-visas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stay in the airport transit area without a transit visa. There are airside hotels, so you do not necessarily need a visa at all. But if you want to pass immigration and enter Dubai, you can use this process:

Since you booked your flight with flydubai, you can apply for the 96-hour transit visa which lets you leave the airport and enter Dubai. You can do this at any of flydubai's [travel shops](https://www.flydubai.com/en/contact/travel-shops). There are travel shops in Istanbul and Sialkot (so you can also get one if you leave again) and most other cities which flydubai serves. I cannot tell what, if anything, the charge is for the visa.

Unfortunately flydubai does not have a process to apply for the transit visa online, as Emirates and Etihad do.

This visa can only be obtained in advance, not on arrival.